# MongoDB Installation Error on Windows 8.1: exception: connect failed

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I want to install MongoDB on Windows 8.1. I have downloaded the mongodb.msi (version 3.0.7, 64-bit 2008 R2+) from mongodb.org. I followed each step on the installation document but I get the error 'exception: connect failed' when I run this command in CMD 'c:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe'.

Note: I have already created c:\data\db folder.

This is the snapshot of CMD Prompt when I run mongod.exe from the command 'c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe'

[image]

And this is the snapshot of the cmd prompt when I run mongo.exe from the command 'c:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe'

[image]

Comment: Since your logs can not be read because they overflow your screenshots, I doubt you'll get a useful answer. Please copy the output instead of making a screenshot.

Comment: During installation with .exe, click allow when there is a pop-up regarding firewall

Comment: are you trying on two different windows..